# Swift: Failed to import bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

I get this error when i run my application with objective-c libraries and swift classes.
It says that i:

> Failed to import bridging header '/Users/../Projectname-Bridging-Header.h'

This file has been created when i imported the swift classes into my project. I've also enabled and set the name for 'defined module' in build settings/packaging with no succes. Inside the bridging-header.h file, the library header files written in objective-c are not found.

[image: xCode image]

I'm running xCode 6.0.1

Comment: You can create it manually, basically its empty header file, just give the same name `Projectname-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: @MaximShoustin It is created in my project navigator. It's already linked in Project build settings / Swift compiler - Code generation / Objective-C Bridging header. I've used the absolute path as the relative path which hasn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

I've forgot to add the frameworks for the specific targets in my pod file.

```
target "MyTarget" do
  pod 'MyFramework', '~> 2.1'
end
```